# Running remote VI on the local computer

Tags: labview

I had a very complicated project which is yet undergoing and User Interface is changed every week.

The architecture of the system I am developing much more looks like this: 
[image]

There are many (>20) User interfaces (they are the same exe, running on different PCs and communicating with servers over TCP), and 3 big servers collecting, controlling, analyzing the data. Everything works great with the system. The problem I have now is GUI update. When I change something on GUI I have to distribute new .EXEs to clients (>20), because I have no access to these users' computers, and sometimes they are not connected to the internet.

What I was thinking is implemented web basics for LabVIEW. So user interfaces are physically located on the servers (whom I have physical access). Users have .EXE which is doing the following:

- upon the run, they download the UI from the server and asynchronously load it locally.

Hence, changing the UI VI only on the server I update the UI everywhere.

**QUESTION 1**: Do you have such an experience, and is there any other solution to this?

**QUESTION 2**: Is there a nice way of doing this? LabVIEW Remote VI call over VI server runs the VI remotely, but on the server :). I need a way to download and run it locally.

PS. I am aware of downloading the VI using FTP, WebDAV and just Asynchronously calling it. But I am looking for a nicer solution.

Thank you, 
Khachik

Comment: I assume that moving to a completely web-based UI (served from the server machines) is not an option? Does the client code need to access local resources on the client, or does it use any particularly advanced UI features that would be hard to implement in a web interface?

Comment: The second option, In the future it might be shifted to the web (using web-sockets), but now we are using almost Real-time big data streaming, showing on the Graphs, scaling this graphs, zooming, etc.. which will cause problems on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a better solution than dynamically loading the UI VI.

However, rather than rolling your own code to download and install the updated code each run, how about taking advantage of your version control system to do this? Users start the client software by running a small loader program - it could even be a batch file or shell script - that performs an update, pulling any changes from the master repository hosted on the server(s) to the local repository. Then it starts the main executable, which dynamically loads the latest version of the UI code.

Each user PC would just need the command-line client for the VCS to be installed and suitably configured - or you could [embed git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-Libgit2), for example in your loader app, and if using git or Mercurial then your 'master' repository can just be a network file share rather than an actual server.

This wouldn't be suitable for a widely deployed, 'production-standard' application but it sounds as if your environment is such that it doesn't have to be a completely unbreakable and foolproof implementation.

Other options along the same lines could be to use a tool like rsync, or Microsoft SyncToy.

Comment: Can be a good solution, the problem is clients should have VCS installed, or I should install with the UI installer. Also, I have to run VCS servers on my servers. 
Anyway, this option is a little bit better than manually downloading the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronously calling downloaded VIs does not sound nice to me, too. But how about building an EXE file that downloads another EXE file (the updated UI) from your server and runs it? It would be just like an auto updater as they are used in many softwares and games today. As far as I know, there are no really nice ways to "run a remote UI locally" this way (and if there were, they would work just the same, by downloading and calling VIs). Unless, of course, you build a UI using web pages.